# How do I find a lost item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whilst exploring some caves I made a chest and stored my map in it for safekeeping. Now I can't find the location of the chest containing my map.

It seems to me that tools like eihort can read the data which describes where everything is. So in principle, it must be possible to search that data for a specific item.

Is there such a tool?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are tool out there that can find a specific block.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried this myself however you could install MCEdit and use a block finder addon filter to locate all the chests in your world. This will require that you have the map downloaded if this isn't on Singleplayer though.